# How can the implication metrizable -> first countable be generalized?

Tags: general-topology, first-countable, metrizability

I'm making a [contribution](https://github.com/pi-base/data/pull/244) to the pi-Base to automatically deduce certain spaces are not metrizable based on the lack of first-countability. How can this theorem be generalized to deduce more [non-]properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pi-Base actually already knows [pseudometrizable implies first-countable](https://topology.pi-base.org/theorems/T000057). It could also be improved by adding local metrizability as a sufficient condition, but pseduometrizable doesn't imply local metrizability, so there's a bit of a disconnect there.

So here's an approach. Say a space is locally [pseudo]metrizable if every point has a [pseudo]metrizable neighborhood (and therefore a basis of such neighborhoods, so it's not a ["weak" local property](https://github.com/pi-base/data#local-properties)).

Then we have the following:

- Metrizable ->(1) pseudometrizable ->(2) locally pseudometrizable ->(3) first countable
- Metrizable ->(2) locally metrizable ->(1) locally pseudometrizable ->(3) first countable

Proofs:

1. Every metric is a pseduometric.
2. The entire space is the desired neighborhood.
3. Take a pseduometrizable neighborhood with pseudometric $\rho$. Then $\{B_\rho(x,\epsilon):\epsilon\in\mathbb Q^+\}$ is a countable local base at $x$.

(I'm unaware of any actual use of "locally pseduometrizable" in the literature, but it seems to be a natural intermediate concept.)